# SQL/MySQL: SELECT sum() with JOIN VS SELECT with subselect/subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

Anyone could explain me which query is more performant and which is the difference behind the scene?

```
SELECT PRODUCT.id, SUM(PRODUCTION.quantity)
FROM PRODUCT 
LEFT JOIN PRODUCTION ON PRODUCT.id = PRODUCTION.product_id
GROUP BY PRODUCT.id
```

versus

```
SELECT 
    PRODUCT.id, 
    (SELECT SUM(quantity) 
     FROM PRODUCTION 
     WHERE PRODUCTION.product_id = PRODUCT.id)
FROM PRODUCT
```

The two queries produces the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Both the queries are not same. In the first query you are using LEFT OUTER JOIN, but in the sub query you are joining with product_id which is a inner join.

Now in the performance, this would provide you good performance compared to a sub query

```
SELECT PRODUCT.id, SUM(PRODUCTION.quantity)
FROM PRODUCT LEFT JOIN PRODUCTION ON PRODUCT.id = PRODUCTION.product_id
GROUP BY PRODUCT.id
```

Answer (score 0):

With the right indexes, the subquery will probably work better than the `LEFT JOIN` version.

The reason is simple:  it avoids the aggregation over the entire table, which MySQL usually implements by sorting the data (an expensive operation).  That said, some databases (but I don't think MySQL is one of them) have special optimizations when the aggregation key is a primary key.

The index that you want on the table is `production(product_id, quantity)`.

As with any performance question, though, you should try the two versions on your data and your system.